# Changing Day Date of <td> using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to change all the table Due Date values from the 31st to the 25th using jquery. The current code I am using is not working, as it is putting all values instead of the single  value.

```js
         var dueDate1 = $("td:contains(/31/)").text();
         var dueDate = dueDate1.replace(/31/g, "25");
         $("td:contains(/31/)").text(dueDate);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Due Date</th>
            <th>Amount</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>    
        <tbody>
            <tr>
            <td data-title="Due Date">08/31/21</td>
            <td data-title="Amount">$500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td data-title="Due Date">07/31/21</td>
            <td data-title="Amount">$1500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td data-title="Due Date">06/31/21</td>
            <td data-title="Amount">$2500</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your attempt is working on the entire set of data all at once.

`$("td:contains(/31/)").text();` will return all the text of all the cells.

Instead, loop through the cells and update them individually.

```js
$("td:contains('31')").each(function(idx, element){
  $(element).text($(element).text().replace("31", "25"));
});
```

```css
td { padding:2px; border:1px solid grey; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Due Date</th>
            <th>Amount</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>    
        <tbody>
            <tr>
            <td data-title="Due Date">08/31/21</td>
            <td data-title="Amount">$500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td data-title="Due Date">07/31/21</td>
            <td data-title="Amount">$1500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td data-title="Due Date">06/31/21</td>
            <td data-title="Amount">$2500</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! Answer worked perfectly.